# R as a backend processing engine

Tags: r

I have an R script that process a CSV file and spit out result as CSV. This work fine in desktop environment.

Now I would like to implement some think like this:

1. set up an email where user could send CSV file as attachment
2. On a server, have an program to check email automatically and pass the CSV file to a specific folder (I don't know exactly how to do this, but I have people in the team to do this)
3. Every time when there are new CSV file come into the folder, get R to pick up this CSV file and run the script. The result is a new CSV file.
4. Deliver the result back to the user by sending an email.

I'm kind of stuck on number 3. Did anyone setup R (or R server) to run in this fashion. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about statistics.

Comment: This question is only about how to get R to do something, & not about any related statistical issues. Thus it is off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Moreover, it isn't really a programming question in [Stack Overflow's](http://stackoverflow.com/) sense, as it isn't a problem w/ specific code you are using & doesn't have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536), so it would be off-topic on SO as well. You could try asking on the r-help-listserv.

Comment: This question is more adequate for a place like StackOverflow.com If you are running a Linux server, this is ridiculously easy to do with a Bash script using 3, maybe 4 lines of code. See `?mutt`, `?sleep`, `?mv`, and use `R CMD BATCH` to execute workhorse functions.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of operating system are you running?  You can run R in non interactive mode with: R --slave.  You could set this up on crontab (as a bash script or some other language that could call R) to run on a particular folder every X minutes,hours, days, etc.  You could send an email with sendmail in bash.